# check if file in folder already exist based on conditional statment

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have two folders

- C:\Folder1
- C:\Folder2

Both folder contain *.txt files with different numbered files names (eg. 01.txt, 02.txt...10.txt)

The script compares files present in both folders. Then only copies files from "Folder1" which aren't present in the "Folder2" or viceversa to C:\TestFolder.

For example if:

- Folder1 contains a single File called 10.txt
- Folder2 contains multiple files 02.txt,10.txt

Then 02.txt would be the only file that is copied to C:\Testfolder.

I would to modify below script to add the following functionality:

- If the file present in Folder1 is newer then "all" the files in  Folder2: do nothing.
- If the file in the Folder1 is newer then "some" of the file on the Folder2: copy the newer files to Folder3.

Basically I need to check if the file present in Folder1 already exists in  Folder2. Also verify if this file is the same, or if a newer version of a file/files are present in Folder2.

```
Compare-Object $Folder1 $Folder2 -Property Name, Length , LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item "C:\Source\$($_.name)"  -Destination "C:\TestFolder" -Force -recurse -include "*.txt"
}
```

Comment: Look at `robocopy` - it probably has an option (or group of options) you can use that will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$folder1="c:\folder1"
$folder2="c:\folder2"
$dest="c:\testfolder"
$folder1Files=dir $folder1
$folder2Files=dir $folder2
$newestFileFolder2=$folder2Files | sort LastWriteTime | select -expand LastWriteTime -Last 1
$equalFiles=diff $folder1Files $folder2Files -Property Name,Length -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -PassThru | select Name,LastWriteTime,FullName
foreach ($file in $equalFiles){
    #If the file present in Folder1 is newer then "all" the files in Folder2: do nothing
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt $newestFileFolder2){
        #If the file in the Folder1 is newer then "some" of the file on the Folder2: copy the newer files to Folder3.
        if ((dir "$folder2\$($file.Name)").LastWriteTime -gt $file.LastWriteTime){
            copy "$folder2\$($file.Name)" $dest -Force -recurse -include "*.txt"
        }
        else{
            copy "$($file.FullName)" $dest -Force -recurse -include "*.txt" 
        }
    }
}
```